# How to prove that for any real number $a$, $A+aI_n$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let an $n$-order real square matrix $A$ satisfy $A^{2m}+I_n=0$, where $m$ is a positive integer. Prove that for every real number $a$, the matrix $A+aI_n$ is invertible. I don't know how to start.

Comment: Saying that $A+aI_n$ is invertible is saying that $-a$ is NOT an eigenvalue of $A$.  If $(A^m)^{2}=-I$, then what can you say about the eigenvalues of $A^m$?  Of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by absurdum we had $A+\alpha I$ not invertible, then there would exist a $v \ne \mathbf{0}$ such that :

$(A+\alpha I)v=\mathbf{0}$

so that $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-\alpha$.

Now:

$\mathbf{0}=(A^{2m}+I)v=((-\alpha)^{2m}+1 )v \ne \mathbf{0}$

, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to avoid eigenvalues?

Comment: you can rewrite the proof with a different terminology of course, but the concepts are always the same (quite basic)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try multiplying your matrix $A + aI$ by
$$
   \sum_{i=0}^{2m-1} (-1)^{i + 1} a^i A^{2m -1 - i}
$$
and simplify. Can you see why the product is invertible?

(Whenever you see something of the form $I + A$ (or even $aI + A$ as in this case), your mind should immediately jump to the [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series).)

Comment: Are you proposing a different approach because the more elementary one has some issue or just to get a different point of view ? +1 anyway ;)

Comment: @Thomas This approach avoids eigenvalues which the original poster seemed to be interested in. Maybe I should have mentioned that explicitly.

Comment: I see thanks for clarifying